# what is the probability that insertions into a hash table will cause atleast 1 collision?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a hash table of size $50$ which contains $30$ elements at different locations.

What is the probability that the next two insertions will cause at least one collision? (Assume a random hash function)

My approach :

**Case 1** A collision during the first insertion and no collision during the second insertion:

$P(case1) = \frac{30}{50} \cdot \frac{19}{50}$

**Case 2** A no collision during the first insertion and a collision during the second insertion:

$P(case2) =\frac{20}{50} \cdot \frac{31}{50}$

**Case 3** Collisions during both insertions:

$P(case 3) = \frac{30}{50} \cdot \frac{31}{50}$

The above three probabilities adds to $0.848$.

What's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: What makes you think the answer is wrong?

Comment: It's probably easier in this case to calculate the probability that the two insertions do not cause a collision, then subtract that answer from 1.

Comment: The answer is right.